# ¿Cómo firmar electronicamente desde php?

Tags: php, firma-digital

Quiero firmar documentos desde `php`, tengo un `token safenet`, creo haber exportado la firma en archivos `.cer` luego los convertí a `.pem` con `openssl`, pero no entiendo como lograr firmar estos documentos desde `php`.

Comment: Disculpa, no comprendo muy bien tu pregunta, lo que deseas es sacar los archivos `.pem` desde `PHP` ?

Comment: Hola, echa un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707794/how-to-digitally-sign-a-file-in-php

Comment: Estimado Andrés lo que quiero es fimar un documento desde php, lo que explicaba que desde el token(usb) exporte la clave en un .cer y esa clave la converti a .pem para tratar de firmar, pero no logro firmar el documento desde php.